# Why volume of the table increase during repairing cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, repair

when i start to repair the table in cassandra cluster until repair is completed, volume of the table increases extremely. This issue is more serious when the volume of the table is higher and causes the hard drive to be filled before the repair is completed,so both repairing remains incomplete and writing in nodes is not done.

Why volume of the table increase during repairing cassandra?
Is there any way to avoid this problem?

Comment: Cassandra nodes should keep 50% disk space free for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are observing as increase in disk space during repairs, is due to they way Compaction works in Cassandra.

There are different compaction strategies which mandates different amount of free space being available in the disk. By default "Size tiered compaction" requires 50% of free space in the disk for compactions to occur. Here is the [reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataMaintain.html)

Comment: Any questions/comments on the solution provided. Otherwise remember to accept/upvote the solution provided.

Comment: in my case also this is happening and the final size of tables on disk is almost double after the full repair activity.  Any idea why? Shouldn't compaction reduce the final size of table?